# Triangle ABC of area S and quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Given a triangle ABC of area S. Find the area of the quadrilateral PBQD.

[image]

The answer is : S

Comment: I've tried to make the line AD and DC, so you've got the quadrilateral ADCB, so let the point T, such that, BT is perpendicular to AC. I think the right way is this, but I can't see anything posteriorly that yet ...

Comment: Is $\theta$ "free"? It looks like we must prove this for any given $\theta$ where $A<\theta<\pi$.

Comment: $\theta$ is free... I think it looks like so

Comment: The picture makes it appear the area of the quadrilateral is strictly less than the area of the triangle, visually comparing what pieces are being removed and introduced.

Comment: I could [experimentally verify](http://martin.von-gagern.net/se/MX620389) the statement for free $\theta$. So now I'll start thinking about ways to proove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint:flip $A$ and $P$ to $BC$, check $A'$ and $P'$ with $C$ and $Q$.find their relations. rest is easy.

edit: I put details.

[image]

it is trivial that $PE=P'E=QE,S_{\triangle BPD}=S_{\triangle BP'D}=\dfrac{BP'*KD}{2},S_{\triangle BQD}=\dfrac{BQ'*KD}{2},P'J=JQ,S_{BPDQ}=\dfrac{(BP'+BQ)*KD}{2}=BJ*KD$

so the problem becomes:

$S_{\triangle ABC}=BJ*KD$

To prove is, we have another graphic.

[image]

it is easy to prove

$S_{\triangle BQD}=S_{\triangle BES},S_{\triangle BPD}=S_{\triangle BER}$

so it is remain to prove:  $S_{\triangle AER}=S_{\triangle SEC}$

I left it unless op find it is difficult.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more ?

Comment: By the way, what's the software did you use to do these diagram ?

Comment: @Ewin it is geopad